# checking wether the range of sublist is valid

Tags: flutter, list, dart, sublist

Hi I have a simple list like this:

```
List x=["a","b","c","d","e"];
```

and I would like to check when I print x.sublist(1,10) => it will get "invalid" string result and when I print x.sublist(1,2) =>it will get "valid" string result. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You can either duplicate the logic, or wrap it in a try/catch.  Better instead to wonder what part of your algorithm decides it wants data without regard to the current value and ensure it doesn't try that, or learn to use things like .skip and .take to select items, possibly giving you a shorter or empty list if no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function to test that:

```
bool isValidSublist(List x, int start, int end) {
  return !(start < 0 ||
      start > x.length ||
      end < 0 ||
      end < start ||
      end > x.length);
}

List x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
print(isValidSublist(x, 1, 10) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
print(isValidSublist(x, 1, 5) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
```

Hope this helps.